# Determining whether or not the alternating series test can be applied to the following infinite series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was working on some series calculus questions and am struggling with this particular one:

[image]

This is what I answered:

1. CONV – The graph of $y=\frac{x^3+1}{x^4+1}$ is positive but decreasing for $x\geq 1$. Also, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{n^3+1}{n^4+1})=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{n^3/n^4+1/n^4}{n^4/n^4+1/n^4})=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{1/n+1/n^4}{1+1/n^4})=\frac{0+0}{1+0}=\frac{0}{1}=0$. So, the AST conditions are fulfilled and the series converges.
2. NA – The graph of $y=\frac{x^3+1}{x^3+7}$ is positive but increasing for $x \geq 1$. It's limit is also not equal to zero: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{n^3+1}{n^3+7})=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{n^3/n^3+1/n^3}{n^3/n^3+7/n^3})=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{1+1/n^3}{1+7/n^3})=\frac{1+0}{1+0}=\frac{1}{1}=1$. The AST conditions are not met, so AST cannot be applied in this case.
3. DIV – The graph of $y=\frac{x^{10}+1}{e^x}$ is positive but increasing for $x \geq 1$. Applying L'Hopital's rule multiple times and then taking the limit $=0$. The AST limit condition is met, but not the decreasing sequence one. So, I thought that it diverges, rather than AST not being applicable.
4. NA – The graph of $y=\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}$ not positive for all values for $x \geq 1$. It decreases but then starts increasing between $x=2$ and $x=3$. Although the limit $=0$, not all the AST conditions are met. So, I thought this one was inapplicable.
5. NA – The graph of $y=\frac{x^4+2x}{x^3-1}$ is positive but increasing for $x\geq 2$. Also, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{n^4+2n}{n^3-1})=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{n^4/n^3+2n/n^3}{n^3/n^3-1/n^3})=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{n+2/n^2}{1-1/n^3})=\frac{\infty+0}{1-0}=\frac{\infty}{1}=\infty$. So, the AST conditions are not met and the AST cannot be applied.
6. CONV – The graph of $y=\frac{1}{x^5}$ is positive and decreasing for $x \geq 1$. Also, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{1}{n^5})=0$. So, all the AST conditions are met, and this series converges.

The system shows that at least one answer is incorrect (but not which one).

Can I please get some help on this?

Comment: 3 is decreasing for $x$ large enough